# Can I use powershell to print images?

Tags: image, powershell, printing

does anyone know if it is possible to use powershell for image printing?  (i.e. print files such as png or jpg files)

Out-printer seems to be good for text but not much else

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use .NET classes such as System.Drawing to do this. Check the following link for a quick example on this.

http://monadblog.blogspot.in/2006/02/msh-print-image.html

Answer (score 3):

This here will print jpgs from any given directory you put the script into

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Extension -eq ".jpg") { Start-Process -FilePath $_.FullName -Verb Print }
```

Comment: please be more accurate and provide proper clarification on what is done here.

Comment: Well, "get-childitem -recurse" will recursively go through all directories and subdirectories.<br />
When it finds an object/file, if the extension is a .jpg, it opens the file specified by -FilePath and then initiates the printing process.

So to answer the question, yes, you can print from powershell.

Comment: And thanks for reformatting. This is my first time commenting on Stackoverflow and haven't figured out how to format code (or text for that matter) @VinayPrajapati

Comment: Also, @VinayPrajapati, I'm not sure about this reputation thing but you gave me -1 rep based on not being clear yet i answered the question that you can and provided proof... not sure on the logic of that.