# Printing a PNG-file from inside a PowerShell script on Win10

Tags: powershell, printing, png

I need to print a PNG-file from inside a PowerShell script. Under Win10, to a specific printer. I find a number of solutions for text files, and also for PDFs, but none for image files.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use powershell to print images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104255/can-i-use-powershell-to-print-images)

Comment: Please answer your own question by submitting and actual answer with the solution you found :)

Comment: I found Daniels suggsted link, but never got it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so there is an answer:

```
Start-Process  C:\windows\system32\mspaint.exe -Arg '/p "C:\scripts\testfil.PNG" /pt "\\ourprintserver\skr1234"'
```

Comment: Can't accept my own answer for a couple of days. But: solved

Comment: Found the answer at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a0d21410-2c24-4ed3-bd1c-ab1e9e04f202/printing-image-using-net-framework-in-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell